# Link time error with ndarray-linalg with mkl-stats on Windows

Tags: rust, linker

I'm struggling to understand why this doesn't link on windows

```
use ndarray::{arr2, Array2, ArrayView2};
use ndarray_stats::CorrelationExt;

pub fn covariance<'a>(asset_returns: &ArrayView2<f64>) -> Array2<f64> {
    asset_returns.cov(1.0).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let a1 = [
        0.12449267,
        0.649514822,
        0.902774751,
        0.282322742,
        0.326426493,
        0.249788045,
        0.341706314,
        0.66930267,
        0.025292061,
        0.401988648,
    ];
    let a2 = [
        0.943092659,
        0.659911328,
        0.390185406,
        0.215201967,
        0.750654958,
        0.66367242,
        0.477742043,
        0.246221733,
        0.827330158,
        0.329059682,
    ];
    let asset_returns = arr2(&[a1, a2]);
    dbg!(covariance(&asset_returns.view()));
}
```

with a simple cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "adabelief"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
ndarray = { version = "0.15.6", features = ["rayon", "approx"] }
ndarray-linalg = { version = "0.16.0", features = ["intel-mkl"] }
ndarray-stats = "0.5.1"
```

This is on windows 11 with Rust 1.71.0

It fails with link error

```
= note: adabelief.3q73x7trmjqga117.rcgu.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cblas_sgemm referenced in function _ZN7ndarray6linalg11impl_linalg12mat_mul_impl17h31fca44a3f629230E
          adabelief.3q73x7trmjqga117.rcgu.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cblas_dgemm referenced in function _ZN7ndarray6linalg11impl_linalg12mat_mul_impl17h31fca44a3f629230E
          adabelief.3q73x7trmjqga117.rcgu.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cblas_cgemm referenced in function _ZN7ndarray6linalg11impl_linalg12mat_mul_impl17h31fca44a3f629230E
          adabelief.3q73x7trmjqga117.rcgu.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cblas_zgemm referenced in function _ZN7ndarray6linalg11impl_linalg12mat_mul_impl17h31fca44a3f629230E
          D:\adabelief\target\debug\deps\adabelief.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

I can build the ndarray-linalg crate separately, in order to identify if there was a missing library, but this works fine

`cargo run --example eigh --features=intel-mkl-static`

but I cannot figure out how to push that dependency up to my own mini test code

Comment: Why are you depending on narray-linalg if you aren't using it? Also your `cargo run` used a different feature than what you have in your `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: @kmdreko I am using it in another file potentially. The point of the answer is to ask why is it needed to be referenced here? It's an unused import.

Comment: I'm just asking questions; I don't have answers (yet). Your answer below is bizarre but I was able to reproduce your issue and indeed the unused import resolves it. I have to assume its something weird going on with the dependency, the compiler, or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger a `cblas_*` linker error with this minimal reproduction:

```toml
[dependencies]
ndarray = { version = "0.15.6", features = ["blas"] }
```

```
fn main() {
    let a = ndarray::arr1(&[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]);
    let b = ndarray::arr1(&[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]);
    let _ = a.dot(&b);
}
```

To give a hint why, the ndarray [feature flag documentation](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/#crate-feature-flags) says (emphasis mine):

> `blas`: transparent BLAS support for matrix multiplication, **needs configuration**.

What "configuration" does it need? It isn't linked to from the documentation, but the BLAS and LAPACK for Rust organization has [this wiki article](https://github.com/blas-lapack-rs/blas-lapack-rs.github.io/wiki) that documents the various crates they have ownership of. The relevant sections are:

> In order to be able to work with the chosen wrapper/binding package, one has to choose a source package as well and add it to the `dependencies` section in `Cargo.toml` along with the wrapper/binding package. For instance, `Cargo.toml` might look as follows:
>
> ```toml
> [dependencies]
> blas = "0.20"
> openblas-src = "0.9"
> ```
>
> #### Sources
>
> The following packages provide concrete implementations of BLAS and LAPACK:
>
> - `accelerate-src` (Apple, macOS only, no LAPACKE)
> - `blis-src` (BLIS)
> - `intel-mkl-src` (Intel MKL)
> - `netlib-src` (Netlib)
> - `openblas-src` (OpenBLAS)

So how is this relevant to you? You didn't enable the `"blas"` feature of ndarray but ndarray-linalg *does*. So ndarray will depend on the cblas-sys crate internally for its bindings but it does not specify one of the concrete implementations above to use. Fortunately, you also enabled the `"intel-mkl"` feature of the ndarray-linalg crate, so it will eventually bring in the intel-mkl-src crate (one mentioned above), and everything is fine.

It is baffling though that this is *not* fine; the compiler appears to build all dependencies, but it seems to skip linking `libintel_mkl_src` into the final binary (presumably because it thinks that whole dependency tree is unused). I did not know the compiler did that. I was able to confirm though by inspecting the output of `RUSTC_LOG=rustc_codegen_ssa::back::link=info cargo build`; any mentions of `libintel_mkl_src-*.rlib` are simply missing in the failing case. I am tempted to call this a bug though who is to blame is not clear; this way of depending on stuff not through Cargo dependencies is quite abnormal in the rest of the ecosystem.

---

To *ensure* the concrete implementation gets linked, you'd have to add it directly to your `Cargo.toml` and add an `extern crate _` declaration in your `main.rs` as indicated in the [wiki link](https://github.com/blas-lapack-rs/blas-lapack-rs.github.io/wiki) above. So yours would look like so:

```toml
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
ndarray = { version = "0.15.6", features = ["rayon", "approx"] }
ndarray-linalg = { version = "0.16.0", features = ["intel-mkl"] }
ndarray-stats = "0.5.1"
intel-mkl-src = "0.8.1"
```

```
// main.rs
extern crate intel_mkl_src;
```

Then it will work for sure regardless whether its "used" or not.

Comment: Yeah this is indeed the investigative path I tried initially. I added the blas feature to ndarray but that didn't solve it. I didn't think we used `extern crate` statements any more so that didn't occur to me. The wiki link indeed does explain it but it's not obvious from the starting point of ndarray-linalg that you have to go down to the eventual lapack crate.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution through trial and error

If you add a `use` for any trait in the linalg crate it will link in the methods needed. I would have expected the linker/compiler to do this automatically but I'm not sure why it wouldn't

```
use ndarray::{arr2, Array2, ArrayView2};
use ndarray_linalg::Solve; // Add this unused trait to fix the link errors
use ndarray_stats::CorrelationExt;

pub fn covariance<'a>(asset_returns: &ArrayView2<f64>) -> Array2<f64> {
    asset_returns.cov(1.0).unwrap()
}

// remaining code below does not change...
```